# tkinter ImportError in Pycharm but works from shell Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
    print("Python 2.X")
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x
    print("Python 3.X")
print("version", tk.TclVersion)
```

If I run from shell with python I get:

```
$ python test_tk
Python 2.X
('version', 8.6)
```

If I run from shell with python3 I get:

```
$ python3 test_tk
Python 3.X
version 8.6
```

But in PyCharm I get ImportError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/PycharmProjects/Project/file.py", line 12, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I looked in PyCharm File>Default Settings>Project Interpreter>+ and it doesnt find any tkinter module...

I tried changing environment and in python 2.x I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

From all the articles I read my conclusion would be that this is a path issue.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: which python interpreter is listed in pycharm?

Comment: Python 3.5 (project). I will try to create a new environment with python3 instead of Python 3.5

Comment: Did you, by any chance create a new venv for your project? You need to specify to use the system interpreter to work

Comment: I tried setting the environment to system python2 and venv python 2 and I still get error